# Url.Action does not call action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following code:

View:

```
<li>
    <a href="<%=bannerImage.Url%>">
    <img src='<%=Url.Action("GetImage", "Image", new {imageName = bannerImage.Image})%>'></a>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string imageName)
{
    var folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"];
    return File(folder + imageName, "image/jpg");
}
```

`GetImage` never fires.
Where is error?

FireBag message: `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8178/error?action=GetImage&controller=Image&imageName=9bbc2035-f753-4212-985b-b6e689150529.Jpeg"`

**EDIT:**
My routes:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Error", "error", "~/Error.aspx");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Cinema Full", // Route name
                "{city}/cinema/{id}/{action}/{subaction}", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Cinema", action = "Overview", subaction = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Cinema", // Route name
                "{city}/cinema", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Cinema", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{subaction}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", subaction = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: What is your routing configuration in global.asax?

Comment: Well, you need to show the code of your `CityConstraint` class as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think url helper call Url.Action("GetImage", "Image", new {imageName = bannerImage.Image}) generates wrong URL using first routing config. Try adding route (at the begining):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "ImageGen", // Route name
        "images/{imageName}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Image", action = "GetImage"} // Parameter defaults
    );
```